# Build PostgreSQL without-ldap Error

Tags: postgresql

I want to configure my new PostgreSQL Server without ldap.  When I execute "gmake world" command it turns out the follwoing error; anybody knows this?

If have tested that if I configure PostgreSQL `--with-ldap`, it is okay!

```
--version
PostgreSQL: Postgresql 9.1 
OS :        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)


--config script
./configure --prefix=/opt/pgsql9.1 --with-pgport=1923 --with-segsize=8 --with-wal-segsize=64 --with-wal-blocksize=64 --with-perl --with-python --with-openssl --with-pam --with-libxml --with-libxslt --enable-thread-safety --without-ldap

--a part of "gmake world" log
 utils/time/tqual.o utils/time/snapmgr.o utils/fmgrtab.o ../../src/timezone/localtime.o ../../src/timezone/strftime.o ../../src/timezone/pgtz.o ../../src/port/libpgport_srv.a -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -ldl -lm -o postgres
libpq/auth.o: In function `InitializeLDAPConnection':
auth.c:(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to `ldap_init'
auth.c:(.text+0x2e7): undefined reference to `ldap_set_option'
auth.c:(.text+0x329): undefined reference to `ldap_start_tls_s'
auth.c:(.text+0x339): undefined reference to `ldap_unbind'
auth.c:(.text+0x37e): undefined reference to `ldap_unbind'
libpq/auth.o: In function `CheckLDAPAuth':
auth.c:(.text+0x163a): undefined reference to `ldap_simple_bind_s'
auth.c:(.text+0x1647): undefined reference to `ldap_unbind'
auth.c:(.text+0x1690): undefined reference to `ldap_simple_bind_s'
auth.c:(.text+0x174c): undefined reference to `ldap_search_s'
auth.c:(.text+0x1768): undefined reference to `ldap_count_entries'
auth.c:(.text+0x1783): undefined reference to `ldap_first_entry'
auth.c:(.text+0x1792): undefined reference to `ldap_get_dn'
auth.c:(.text+0x17c3): undefined reference to `ldap_memfree'
auth.c:(.text+0x17ce): undefined reference to `ldap_msgfree'
auth.c:(.text+0x17d9): undefined reference to `ldap_unbind_s'
auth.c:(.text+0x1929): undefined reference to `ldap_get_option'
auth.c:(.text+0x1964): undefined reference to `ldap_err2string'
auth.c:(.text+0x19c2): undefined reference to `ldap_get_option'
auth.c:(.text+0x19fd): undefined reference to `ldap_err2string'
auth.c:(.text+0x1a42): undefined reference to `ldap_msgfree'
auth.c:(.text+0x1a5e): undefined reference to `ldap_count_entries'
auth.c:(.text+0x1b0a): undefined reference to `ldap_count_entries'
collect2: ld 返回 1
gmake[2]: *** [postgres] 错误 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/soft_bak/postgresql-9.1.0/src/backend'
gmake[1]: *** [all-backend-recurse] 错误 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/soft_bak/postgresql-9.1.0/src'
gmake: *** [world-src-recurse] 错误 2
```

Comment: You may ask this kind of questions on [Database administrators](http://DBA.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I know here is so activite.

Comment: Who can help me miggrate the question to Database Admiinistrators?

Comment: Actually ... no, this wouldn't be appropriate for DBA if you're trying to compile from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first build `--with-ldap` and then without, you need to run `make distclean` in between (or do `configure --enable-depend` in the first run).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , afte exectute the "make distclean" commond before configure , it's okey now !